# protecting DB using Python

Tags: python, sqlite

I just want to set a password to my file "file.db" (SQLite3 database), if someone trying to open this DB it has to ask password for authentication.
is there any way to do this Using python.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Set the appropriate user & group permission on the file itself (on the OS level) rather than encrypting a file. It is more efficient and from security perspective - the better solution

Answer (score 0):

Asking a password when opening a file doesn't make much sense, it will take another program to do that, watching the file and intercepting the request at os level..

What you need to do is protect the file using ACL, setting the proper access rights to only desired users&groups.

Comment: Yes! "another program to do that, watching the file and intercepting the request at os level.."    I want that only. It is helpful to integrate with my project